# different outcome of feature importance and coefficient from same data

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, boosting, predictor-importance

I built a regression model to predict profit based on client, sales person, product category, client industry and client region.

After trying several models with tuning hyperparameters, I found that Gradient Boosting Regressor and Ridge Regression were performing best (they got similar RMSE).

However, when I ran feature importance and coefficient of each model to analyze which features were important for the prediction of profit, it showed that GB Regressor showed client & salesperson as top features while ridge regression had client region and industry as top coefficient.

I realized that I've been thinking coefficient and feature importance as the almost same thing. 
Can someone help me to figure out how should I interpret this result - which one is more meaningful when I want to find the relationship among columns and target?

Comment: What feature importance did you run exactly ? Ar eyour variables correlated ?